# Align two+ pdf images side-by-side, and center the group on page using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment

Say I have a vector drawing in `img.pdf` which is, say, 2x3 cm rectangle, cropped with `pdfcrop --margins '0 0 0 0' img.pdf img-crop.pdf`. Now, I'd like to copy this `img-crop.pdf` image on page in two or three (or more) copies, such that either the group of images forms a row, or a column, of images - whose borders touch exactly.

Then, I'd want this group of images (row or column) as a whole to be centered on page.

For just a single PDF image, I can achieve this with the following MWE (needs texing twice for the centered image to appear on output because of `remember picture, overlay`):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclareimage[page=1]{design}{/home/username/Desktop/img-crop.pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

  \node[anchor=center] at (current page.center) {\pgfbox[center,center]{\pgfuseimage{design}}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How could I do the same, for two copies of `img-crop.pdf`, placed side-by-side either horizontally or vertically?

Comment: Did you try to use `\pgfuseimage{design}` twice, like  `\pgfuseimage{design}\pgfuseimage{design}`?

Comment: Thanks @Sigur - that was my intention, but the alinment and centering is the problem - the two images mostly overlap

Comment: Is there a reason for not using \includegraphics?  Also, since we don't have access to your file, we can't do any testing.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `eso-pic`, `graphicx` and `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \null\AddToShipoutPicture*{\AtPageCenter{%
        \makebox[0pt]{\begin{tabular}{*{3}{@{}c}}
            \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}&
            \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}&
            \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
        \end{tabular}}}}
    \newpage
    \null\AddToShipoutPicture*{\AtPageCenter{%
        \makebox[0pt]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}   
            \begin{tabular}{c}
            \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}\\
            \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}\\
            \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
        \end{tabular}}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]